# Laravel Livewire search auto complete like google search select with keyboard arrow key and hit enter to select

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

Laravel Livewire search auto complete like google search select with keyboard arrow key and hit enter to select

here is my code

```
use Livewire\Component;
 
class SearchUsers extends Component
{
    public $search = '';
 
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.search-users', [
            'users' => User::where('username', $this->search)->get(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
<div>
    <input wire:model="search" type="text" placeholder="Search users..."/>
 
    <ul>
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <li>{{ $user->username }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

but work not lkie google search  want to create POS sale invoice search by name and select product by id using keyboard

Comment: I am trying to make it as well but can't but really I need it :(